# why it's throwing "UsageError: Line magic function `%%capture` not found."

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

[image]

whenever i run the above code shown in the picture it's showing the above error

Comment: `%%capture` must be the first line of the cell in Jupyter in order for it to be recognized correctly.

Answer (score 5):

You have to remove the comment above the magic line `%%capture`

[image]